# proof of $\sin(x)$ infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I can't seem to find a proof for this

$$\sin( x )= x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} – \frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots$$

Which euler used to proof the basel problem.

Would be great if it anyone show us how to this equality

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand the question... could you be more precise?

Comment: I need a proof that sinx is equal to that infinite series

Comment: It looks like you are looking for the Maclaurin series of $\sin x$

Comment: are you familiar with something called taylor series expansion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $\sin x=a_0+a_1 x^1+a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3... $

Note that $\sin 0=0\implies a_0=0$

Now differentiate both sides.

$\cos x = a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2...$

$\cos 0 =1 \implies a_1=1$

Differentiate again

$-\sin x=2a_2+3!a_3x...$

$\sin 0=0 \implies a_2=0$

Differentiate again
$-\cos x=3! a_3...$

$\cos 0 =1 \implies a_3=-\frac{1}{3!}$

Hence you can find the pattern.

Comment: This is the best proof ! Thanks !

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: while it is not a rigorous proof, I think it is best for a beginner and probably more in line with proofs during Euler's time when rigor was not necessary. +1

Comment: You first assume that $sinx$ can be written as a power series, which is not trivial, and then differentiate it term by term, which is not too...This indeed gives efficiently the intuition but this is not a proof, maybe should you include links to more rigourous definitions/proofs ?

Comment: but what is rigorous proof

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is that that is the [Taylor Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) for the sine function expanded around $0$. This is a standard early example of a Taylor series, so any intro text detailing Taylor Series (which is to say, most introductory calculus texts) will contain it and a proof.

If you're not interested in learning the whole theory, then you might be interested in [something I wrote on my personal blog](http://mixedmath.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/an-intuitive-overview-of-taylor-series/) about understanding Taylor series at a much more basic level. It just so happens to be that my example function is $\sin(x)$, and the post contains a proof of that equality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that: 
$$\sin(x) = \dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$ and that:
$$e^{ix} = 1+(ix)+\frac{(ix)^2}{2!}+\frac{(ix)^3}{3!}+\cdots$$
$$e^{-ix} = 1+(-ix)+\frac{(-ix)^2}{2!}+\frac{(-ix)^3}{3!}+\cdots$$

So:

$$\begin{align*}\sin(x) &= \dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} \\ &= (1-1)+ \frac{(ix)-(-ix)}{2i}+\frac{1}{2i}\bigg(\frac{-x^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}\bigg)+\frac{1}{2i}\bigg(\frac{-ix^3}{3!}-\frac{ix^3}{3!}\bigg)+\cdots \\ 
&= 0+\frac{2ix}{2i}+0+\frac{-2ix^3}{2i3!}+\cdots \\
&= x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots\end{align*}$$

Also using the fact that $i^2 = -1, i^3 = -i, i^4 = i, i^5 = -1,$ etc.

Comment: No, I don't think you can. To my knowledge, Euler's formula is deduced from the Taylor series, not the other way around.

Comment: He just asked for a proof for the series. This was the first one I thought of from Complex Analysis.

Comment: @Lucian Really ? In my cursus, we used Euler's formula as a definition for sin and cos (exponential being defined by the power serie) and then derived their expansion...So I think you can do it both way, depending on your definitions